# Use a PHP file to Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I have a PHP file which is connected to elasticsearch, where I am indexing my documents.

My elasticIndex.php file:

```
    **class elasticIndex{ 
function elasticFun(){

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Elasticsearch\Client();

    $feed = 'http://blaasd.zasdp.tv/Xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    foreach ($xml-> .......
    ......}**
```

Now the problem is I am working on Symfony framework, where in the beginning of a PHP file you have to address the namespace, like:

```
**namespace MyBundle\Controller**
```

That is why I am unable to use the following two lines in my controller class:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Elasticsearch\Client();
```

So I have created a new PHP file (elasticIndex.php)and writen code for elasticsearch indexing. So how can I call my function `elasticFun()` from my elasticIndex class to my controller class. for not using the namespace in the elasticIndex class, it is not address anywhere in my Symfony project.
So how can I call my `elasticFun()` function which is not addressed to anywhere from my controller class?

i have also try to use the global namespace like ---

```
**use MyBundle\VideoProviderClient\elasticIndex as _val;
class ExternalClientControlController extends Controller {
    public function ExternalClientControlAction() {
                $_val = new \elasticIndex();
        return new Response($_val);
    }**
```

it gives an error -- **Attempted to load class "elasticIndex" from the global namespace.Did you forget a "use" statement?**

Can anyone kindly help me with this. Thanks a lot in advanced ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the namespace for the ElasticSearch object into your controller class.

Typically this would be done with a use statement near the top of the file (under the namespace declaration for the class), i.e.:

```
namespace MyBundle\Controller

use Elasticsearch;

class index {

    public function indexAction() {
        $client = new Elasticsearch\Client();
    }
}
```

For arbitrary PHP files you can either refactor them into Symfony / Composer's autoloading structure or use the ClassLoader functionality to manually load the classes however best suited for your specific requirements:

> https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader